# Change "logged in" link in (you must be logged in to post a comment)

Tags: customization, comments, login, comment-form

I need to change the link for "logged in" to a user log in url instead of wp login url.
I have checked /wp-includes/comment-template.php and that's what I found on line 2217

```
    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/link-template.php */
    'must_log_in'          => '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf(
                                  /* translators: %s: login URL */
                                  __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ),
                                  wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) )
                              ) . '</p>',
```

If this is the right place to customize the "logged in" link, how should be the code with a new login page url example: yourdomain.com/my-account ??

Comment: I posted an answer, but I am not sure if it is specific enough for your use case. If you explain a little more in detail what you are actually trying to achieve, a more helpful answer can be given.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need. I edited my code as yours and it is working properly now. I also tried your second code and it works well, but I don't want admins to be redirected to the customized login page, so I deleted it again and kept the first one. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the login link only in this template, replace the `wp_login_url()` function call with your login link:

```
'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf(
    /* translators: %s: login URL */
    __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ),
    "https://yourdomain.com/my-account"
    ) . '</p>',
```

If you want to generally redirect users to another url if they need to log in, it is better to use the filter `login_url`:

```
function wpse_258398_login_url ( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    return "https://yourdomain.com/my-account";
}
add_filter( 'login_url', 'wpse_258398_login_url', 10, 3);
```

Be aware though, this will affect all redirects to login. Even when you are redirected to login for the admin backend.