# change wp_login url and redirect users at the same time

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, comments

i use woodmart theme for my woocommerce shop. but in mag(weblog) page if a user want to submit a comment it redirects user to wp-login-url instead of woodmart login page. i found my first part answer in this question
[1]: [Change "logged in" link in (you must be logged in to post a comment)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/258398/193175)
with this code

```
'must_log_in' => '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf(
/* translators: %s: login URL */
__( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ),
"https://yourdomain.com/my-account"
) . '</p>',
```

i put my link ( `"https://yourdomain.com/my-account"` ) instead of this code:

```
wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) )
```

but it redirect users to home page after login instead of current page. i dont know how to redirect users to current page after login. thanks.